# NSString Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

```
NSRange rangetxt={0,(index-1)};
NSString *tempStr= textBox.text;
NSString *tempTextBox=[tempStr substringWithRange:rangetxt];
```

Hi Everyone,

I want to know why my pasted code isn't working properly, when the compiler passes `substringWithRange` It hung up and do not assign any value to `tempTextBox`, Secondly I've tried the NSString function `substringToIndex` as well yet its not working too, My objective is to skip the last character while copying `tempStr` to `tempTextBox`.

Regards
MGD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the code that's initialising `index`. My guess is it's out of range. Note that substringWithRange raises an `NSRangeException` if any part of the range lies beyond the end of the receiver.

Try this:

```
NSString *tempStr = textBox.text;
NSRange rangetxt;
if ([tempStr length] > 0)
    rangetxt = NSMakeRange(0, [tempStr length] - 1);
else
    rangetxt = NSMakeRange(0, 0); 
NSString *tempTextBox = [tempStr substringWithRange:rangetxt];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but lemme tell you that when i remove decrement in in index it works otherwise it troubles, i think my code is right I dunno where i m doin wrong :(

Comment: please, can you paste here some more parts of your code so we can pinpoint with finger?

Comment: `NSRangeMake` should be `NSMakeRange`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `NSMakeRange(loc, len)` to create a NSRange object instead of using *{}*.

Comment: You might also want to do "clean target" in Xcode. Might be some messed up build cache.

Answer (score 2):

I had test this code and it works:

```
NSString *strTest = @"Word";
NSRange range = {0, 3};
NSString *strTemp = [strTest substringWithRange: range];
```

The result: strTemp = "Wor"

So the problem is something else: index is not proper or textBox.text is maybe empty.

Put the breakpoint on your substringWithRange: line and look at the values of index and tempStr before problem appears.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yet I ve checked the index its not out of range I dont why its not working

Answer (score 0):

I think i got my problem solved, During the debug when i pass through these line my gdb says "Timed out fetching data. Variable display may be inaccurate" so i found the solution just placed my break point after the initialization of the NSString objects

Thanks for Help Everyone

MGD